# JS not running inside modal after dynamically change of it's id

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm using bootstrap modal and I'm calling a autocomplete function inside of it, it all works well when it's set like this:

Button that has a data-target to call the id of the modal:

```
data-target="#modalAdicao"
```

And the div with the id set to match the data-target:

```
id="modalAdicao"
```

But because it's called inside a PHP foreach and I need keep the information, I have to set the id of the modal like the id of the mysql line I'm dealing with, like this:

```
data-target="#modalAdicao<?php echo htmlspecialchars($idModal); ?>"
```

And:

```
id="modalAdicao<?php echo htmlspecialchars($idModal); ?>"
```

After this, the information is kept but the js stops working, it's like I never called it, but it's there, like it always been:

```
<script src="js/procura-paciente.js"></script>
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: you called `...modal('show')` in `procura-paciente.js`?

Comment: Nope, how do I do that properly?

Comment: show us your html code

Comment: The whole modal: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FRE50JB52W8T 

The procura-paciente.js file: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FRE5AJUCJI8R

Comment: [It's working](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/kyx6-3z0v)

Comment: It is opening the modal, that wasn't the problem, the problem is that procura-paciente.js is not being called inside the modal, it stops working when I start calling the id concatenated with the id of the line of mysql table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When modal opening, the id is changed and the modal is re-drawn. But the js event is defined.
Try to use this

```
$(document).on('input','.busca', limpaCampos);
```

The `for` loop generate many `#busca`, the `id` is unique. Change to use `class` instead. For example

`php form`

```
<form id="novoAgendamento" method="POST" action="include/novo_agendamento.php">
            <div class="form-inline">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="busca" class="sr-only">Identidade</label>
                <input type="text" id="busca" data-id="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($idModal); ?>" placeholder="Identidade" name="rgPaciente" class="mx-sm-69 form-control busca" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nascimentoPaciente" class="sr-only">Nascimento</label>
                <input type="text" id="nascimentoPaciente" placeholder="Nascimento" name="nascimentoPaciente" class="mx-sm-69 form-control" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="nomePaciente"></label>
              <input type="hidden"  name="nomePaciente" class="form-control nomePaciente">
              <input type="hidden" name="cpfPaciente" class="form-control cpfPaciente">
              <input type="hidden" name="horaPaciente" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($horarios[$i]); ?>" class="form-control horaPaciente">
              <input type="hidden" name="dataPaciente" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($data_agendamento_convert); ?>" class="form-control dataPaciente">
              <input type="hidden" name="medicoPaciente" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($medico_completo); ?>" class="form-control medicoPaciente">
              <input type="text"  placeholder="Nome do Paciente" class="form-control nomePaciente2" disabled="">     
              <label for="observacaoPaciente"></label>
              <input type="text" name="observacaoPaciente" placeholder="Observação" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">Fechar</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agendar</button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

js

```
$(function() {
 $('#tableteste').on('input', '.busca', function(){
    var busca = $(this).val();
    var form = $(this).parents().eq(2);
    if(busca == ""){
    form.find('.nomePaciente').val('');
        form.find('.nomePaciente2').val('');
        form.find('.rgPaciente').val('');
        form.find('.nascimentoPaciente').val('');
        form.find('.cpfPaciente').val('');
    }
});
.....

});
```

Comment: Not working, I don't think the ID changes because it's on a loop, it only changes when we hit the button that calls the modal on the next line, here's the complete code so you can understand what's going on the whole picture. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FRE6QZB89CDZ

Comment: Change all id in modal into class, ID is only one in a page.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understood what you mean.

Comment: You used `for loop`. The `#busca` generated `count($horarios)` times. I think it raises problems because ID is unique. [Read more](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Comment: I see, but without that I can't relate the content of the modal to the right like on my for,  this modal is supposed to be used to edit the selected line, when I am not using the variable $id to iterate the modal id this is what happens https://imgur.com/a/bbmj19q when I select 11:00 the modal gives me the first option available to edit, which in this case is 09:00.

Comment: Actually, the fist ID availabe IS WORKING, which made me realize it needs something to all the options be editable.

Comment: Use `class` and `data-id`. My example above